# Install ubuntu from usb when there is only win 8 on computer

Tags: installation, boot, windows, windows-8

Now there is only single win8 OS on my laptop. How I create usb with ubuntu installer, but after reboot win 8 with sytem repair and nothing ubout ubuntu installation. I have cheked BIOS settings: usb is first. PS I want to repalce win 8 by ubuntu

Comment: 1. make a bootable usb stick. 
2. boot from it choose "use all my hdd, replace windows with Ubuntu" in the partition option.
3. Done!

Comment: I write that I can't boot from usb for some reason. When i try to boot from it my win 8 is running again.

Comment: Have you looked in BIOS that the usb is in the boot list? tried a different USB? Do you know what keys to press to boot from the USB?  Did you try to install Ubuntu on the USB again? (format then reinstall), these are just things we need to know that you've tried.

Comment: I checkd that USB is first in BIOS boot list. I did not try to format  USB and write it again. Thanks for idea - I'll it tomorrow (it's deep night here)

Comment: You need to edit your question , without creating Live USB , your system cannot boot from it, as no Boot Image is found , so it Boots into Windows 8 by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the flash drive. With CD everything was installed properly. The appearance of the error windows at the same time as trying to install Ubuntu made me very confused.

Answer (score 1):

Download [Unetbootin for windows](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and then from Unetbootin select the Ubuntu ISO image as per image

[image]

Select the `Diskimage` option , then Browse to the location of the Ubuntu ISO image from the `....` button.

**IMPORTANT** option , select the `Type` and `Drive` Option Very Carefully to avoid data loss . If it is `Usb Drive` , most probably will be **sdbX** , **sdcX**, do a cross check and Proceed with OK option.

---

Until you create a **Live Bootable USB Disk** from above method , USB Drive **cannot** boot .

If you want to replace your Windows 8 installation do follow this Answered question here as

[How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

As you said , if you want to replace Windows , then from this [illustrated answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/152902/63025) at this option

[image]

Select the second Option as `Replace windows with Ubuntu`.

Comment: I *can not boot* from usb. How can I check my stick?

Comment: I have already used this(UNetbootin) programm

Comment: @xander27- I would recommend you to edit your question and include this info to post what exactly you did , and at what part you need help.